# How to select rows in data.table with dynamically determined column name and cut off limits?

Tags: r, data.table

I'd like to write a function that selects rows from a data table that fall within a certain range for a dynamically named column. Trying to write this, I find myself unable to do row selection by applying criteria to a dynamically determined column. Here's my examples:

This works fine:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(weight=seq(150, 250, 10))
dt[weight < 200]
```

As does this:

```
x = 200
dt[weight < x]
```

But this doesn't work

```
name = weight
limit = 200
dt[eval(name) < limit]
```

What's my workaround here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need two things:

1. Your variable `name` should be a character string, as in `"weight"`.
2. You need to call `eval(parse(text=name))`, not just `eval(name)`.

For example, with some fake data:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(weight=seq(150,250,10))

name <- "weight"
limit <- 200
dt[eval(parse(text=name)) < limit]
#    weight
# 1:    150
# 2:    160
# 3:    170
# 4:    180
# 5:    190
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use either `as.name` or `as.symbol`

```
dt[eval(as.name(name))< limit]
```

Or

```
dt[eval(as.symbol(name))< limit]
```

#### data

```
dt <- data.table(weight = c(150, 70, 250, 320), col2= LETTERS[1:4])
limit <- 200
name <- 'weight'
```

Comment: Is this answer still current? I have tried to use ..name and (name) but neither works.

Comment: @HermanToothrot It is working for me (based on the example showed in my post)

Comment: Indeed your example is working, I was just asking if with the newer versions of the data.table package there is a built in way to do the same. In other similar questions it seems that the eval is not the best option.

Comment: @HermanToothrot You can also specify it in `.SDcols` `dt[dt[, .SD[[1]] < limit, .SDcols = name]]`

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility, using `get()`:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(weight = seq(150, 250, 10))

name <- "weight"
limit <- 200
dt[get(name) < limit]

   weight
1:    150
2:    160
3:    170
4:    180
5:    190
```

Answer (score 0):

Spoiler alert

Using the yet to come metaprograming in `data.table` (next release, already in dev) that use a custom `substitute` function.

```
name = "weight"
limit = 200
dt[name<limit, env=list(name=name, limit=limit)]
```

If `limit` was a string, you'll have to enclose it in `I()` to prevent considering the value to be a var name.